# deployment of local parse server using the Back4app-Cli

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

I followed the back4app tutorial to run parse locally:

https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/parse-server-local

The Parse dashboard is well launched. But when trying to deploy the cloud code by running "b4a deploy", I get the following error:

```
Command must be run inside a Parse project.
```

I know that I, normally, run this command from the folder containing the parse server code.
But, I don't find where to find this folder since after running the following command (using my own back4app credentials), no files or folder created inside the current folder:

```
parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --clientKey CLIENT_KEY --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/my-app --cloud /path/to/your/cloud/code/folder/main.js
```

Could you tell me where to find the parse server folder from which I have to run b4a deploy command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, what you need to do is have an app created at Back4App, if you don't have one, please create the app following [these steps](https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/get-started/new-parse-app).

So, you must connect to an existing App via CLI using the `b4a new` command in your terminal. Type (e) and select the number for the name of the application you want to configure.

Right after, you should be a new folder created at your computer and it is where your app is deployed. Access the cloud code function directory by typing the `cd` command.

Now, you should be able to run the `b4a deploy` command.

To get the path, you can use `pwd` command in Linux or `%cd%` in Windows.

I hope that it helps!